# What is the workflow for code signing an AppleScript applet for Catalina/Big Sur?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have an applet which installs an add-in for PowerPoint. It requires automation to send AppleEvents to the PowerPoint application. Here's a simplified example:

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    display alert "bla bla bla"
end tell
```

I export this from the Script Editor as an **Application**, with **Run Only** enabled, and **Don't Code Sign**.

I then manually sign it in Terminal with these three commands:

```
xattr -cr "/users/username/documents/myApplet.app"
codesign -f -s "Developer ID Application: bll bla bla" --options=runtime "/users/username/documents/myApplet.app"
spctl --assess -vvv "/users/username/documents/myApplet.app"
```

Note: --options=runtime is required to set hardened runtime for notarization.

If I don't sign it, when I run the applet Gatekeeper prompts me to allow Apple events:

[image: Gatekeeper permission]

and when I click OK the applet runs, displaying the alert:

[image: PowerPoint alert]

After signing and running it, I get the following error:

**Not authorised to send Apple events to Microsoft PowerPoint.**
Not authorised to send Apple events to Microsoft PowerPoint.(-1743)

[image]

System Preferences shows the rule in the Automation tab with the checkbox ticked for myApplet / Microsoft PowerPoint.

If I then remove the signature with the following command, the applet works as normal again:

```
codesign --remove-signature "/users/username/documents/myApplet.app"
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: What happens if you uncheck the _app_ and then recheck it, will it run without error then?

Comment: No. That doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from another developer is to use the --entitlements parameter with a corresponding plist file. Example:

```
codesign -f --entitlements ents.plist -s etc.
```

And example plist file for AppleEvents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "[domain redacted for post]/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.automation.apple-events</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```